# How should posts with malicious URLs be handled?

Tags: discussion, posts, malicious-links

I recently found a question on Stack Overflow which asked why a corrupt video would cause an iOS device to hang or crash: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41370136/2415822

While the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, I was also concerned about the malicious nature of the link.  The first thing I did was edit the hyperlink into a code block so that users wouldn't accidentally click on it, but then I decided to take it one step further and flag the question as abusive.  The flag was disputed, and while I understand why (it wasn't purposefully malicious and a mod decided that a nuke wasn't necessary), I would like to start a dialog on the topic.

If a post contains a malicious URL, what action should be taken?  Should it be edited into a code block?  Edited out completely?  Should the post be flagged?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara because I've done some [research on it previously](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/14027/17972).  Also if the OP says the video crashes their phone, users should be concerned.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I assume OP meant "harmful" rather than "posted with the intention to harm"

Comment: Ok, if the post and link is intentionally abusive/malicious/spam, you shouldn't edit because it makes it harder to delete via flags. Otherwise, IDK.

Comment: I think the link needs to be removed entirely. the edit history will show it if the mods need to see why a question should be removed.

Answer (score 7):

If a post contains a URL that takes you to a site capable of harming your device, it should definitely be edited:

- If it's an intentionally harmful link/post, such as "Click here to enter your SO credentials and get as much rep as Jon Skeet in 15 minutes!", which takes you to a site to steal your money and SO credentials, edit out the link and flag the post for moderators, or simply flag as spam if it is spam, et cetera.
- If it's an unintentionally harmful link/post, such as when a user is asking "Why does this link cause my iPhone to freeze", I would suggest editing the link into either a spoiler tag or out of the question entirely.

In this second case, I don't think flagging for a moderator is useful, because it's not a case of someone trying to abuse the site or its users. A comment might be helpful, however, in explaining to the OP and to future visitors why the link is not immediately visible in the post anymore.

Comment: "edit out the link and flag the post for moderators/flag as spam/etc." - one shouldn't edit spam posts. And, if the link text is what you suggest, it should be obvious where it leads = not an exception to the non-edit rule.

Comment: @JanDvorak You're free to handle spam posts the way you like, but if a spam post is very new and likely to fly under the radar for more than a few minutes, I'll edit it if necessary. Also, that link text is obviously just an example, where an obvious example is needed to get the point across. It could also just be a link to a random website like xyz.com/index.html that has terrible malware on it.

Comment: Also it should be noted that a spam post is only one of many kinds of posts that could have a potential harmful link it, and the percentage of scenarios where I would edit a spam post with a harmful link in it are probably less than 1%. It's a minor detail meant to cover edge cases, not a major focus of the suggested behavior.

Comment: @TylerH *Please* don't edit spam. This is one of the few things that does actually make fighting spam harder. It makes the spam less obvious (so it gets fewer flags and doesn't get deleted as fast - this goes double for posts that are already borderline), and it confuses humans who are looking for spam and can't find any - an edited spam post will often produce confusion in Charcoal HQ, where we find and flag spam. SpamRam doesn't *currently* do anything with post content, but if it was modified to do so and you didn't realise, editing the post would *actively harm* spam-detection.

Comment: Editing spam posts and posts like this make it difficult for moderators and other users to handle. If you don't raise a custom flag explaining exactly what the problem is and what you've done a moderator may well just dismiss your flag as unhelpful.

Comment: I have slightly modified my throwaway example of flagging for spam since it apparently wasn't clear and everyone was focusing on that instead of the other 95% of the answer.

Answer (score 7):

The problem occurs if it's not immediately obvious that the link is malicious, so while editing the post would appear to be the right thing to do, it can cause delays in dealing with the post correctly.

For example, editing to put the link into a code block can help, but may cause confusion to those coming along afterwards. If it's not immediately apparent that there's a problem with the post, users (and moderators) may well take action which keeps the post on the site for longer than would otherwise be the case.

Leave a comment explaining that the link is apparently malicious. This will alert future viewers and also the OP, who may not be aware that there are problems with the link. This could be particularly true for older posts where the link could be pointing to a site that is no longer what it once was.

Flag the post as spam or as rude/abusive. This will get the post to the front of the moderators flag queue where it will be seen and dealt with quite quickly. Don't forget you can always use a custom flag if none of the standard ones fit the circumstances, so in cases where you're not 100% sure this would be the better option.

Post a comment in the site's most active chat room, or choose one of the more popular general rooms where there are likely to be people around who'll double check and add their flags if appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  The only issue I have with flagging is that flags may be declined or disputed depending on if the mod feels a nuke is needed.  I'm not worried about disputed flags, but I would just like clarity on when to flag.  Do you think a flag was warranted in this case?

Comment: @JAL a flag was probably warranted, but I wouldn't have edited the post. You can always use a custom flag if none of the standard ones fit the circumstances.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll lean towards custom flagging and not editing these types of posts in the future.

Comment: IMHO this *particular* posts shouldn't really be flagged. It's no different than a "why does this code crash my system?" type of question. Including the code (or video) which causes the problem is not just helpful, but *required* to provide a good answer to the question. Making it non-clickable *is* probably a good idea though, since some people may click the link accidentally or before reading the description.